# preg_replace, make $1 to variable

Tags: php

I have this variable that makes every word with @ into a link. But now i need that value made into a variable to create a function.
Pretty hard to explain so i'll show it with code.

```
$text = preg_replace( "/@([^\s]+)/", "<a href=\"profile.php?id=$1\" class=\"at\">@$1</a>", $text);
```

Here is the variable, what i want is `$1` made into a variable. I've tried to fix this but i just cant because i dont know how to do it. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want to get the value of a variable that's named what `$1` contains?  Or do you want to save `$1` as a variable *outside* of this line?

Comment: I've no idea what you're trying to achive. Are you looking for preg_match()?

Comment: Your code is already working.

Comment: `$text = "... and so @JacobJ said to me...";` should become (in HTML) `$text = "... and so <a href="profile.php?id=JacobJ" class="at">@JacobJ</a> said to me...";` (with interior " suitably escaped)? Unless @ has some special meaning in PHP (it does in Perl), it ought to work. What results are you getting? Is it adding the <a> tag but not properly substituting the $1?

Comment: The preg_replace is working fine. What I want is to pass the @[VALUE] to a function to check if the user exists.

Answer (score 2):

```
function makeALink($value) {
    // Do something here with $value, for example make a link
    return "<a href=\"profile.php?id=$value\" class=\"at\">@$value</a>";
}

$text = preg_replace_callback("/@([^\s]+)/", "makeALink", $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `preg_match_all()` in stead of preg_replace.

```
$matches = array();
preg_replace_all("/@([^\s]+)/", $text, $matches);

// $matches[0] contains the with @. $matches[1] contains your hits without the @
echo $matches[1][0]; // your first hit without the @
echo $matches[1][1]; // your second hit without the @
echo $matches[1][2]; // your third hit without the @
```